# Create new thread for each method in same class

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a server class with many methods. For each method I would like to create new thread. Server can treat only 10 concurrent requests.

```
public class Server {   

    private ArrayList<Client> clients=new ArrayList<>();// CRITICAL SECTION

    private ArrayList<Stock> stocks=new ArrayList<>(); //CRITICAL SECTION
    private int currentRequests;
    private final int MaximumRequest=10; //maximum current requests.

    public synchronized  void  updateStockValue(Stock st) {
        //do something with stocks list;
    }

    public synchronized void addNewUser(Client cl) {
        //do something with clients list
    }
}
```

And my test class :

```
public class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Server server=new Server();
        Client client= new Client();
        Stock stock=new Stock();
        /* all I want to do in the test class methods like : */ 

        server.updateStockValue(stock);

        server.addNewUser(client);              
    }
}
```

Does it possible for each method from the Test class, create thread in respective method in the server class?

Comment: I removed the `computer-science` tag as I felt it was too generic

Comment: The code as-is will not compile. calls `server.updateStockValue(st);` and `server.addNewUser(client);` must be within a method.

Comment: Turing85, thank you..I've edited the Test class.

Answer (score 0):

You want a thread pool to handle requests:

```
Executor pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // There are at most 10 concurrent request handler running, 
                                                  // new requests will be putted in queue
```

When a new request comes, you do:

```
pool.submit(() -> server.updateStockValue(stock));
```

But I think, you should make a synchronization at your `list` level, not a class level like this:

```
public synchronized  void  updateStockValue(Stock st) {
 //do something with stocks list;
}
```